# How can I set environment variable permanently through shell script?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

Let's say I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
    echo "True"
fi
export ABC="/home/aashish"
```

`ABC` is not available after the execution of this script. How can I make that variable persist after the execution as well?

Comment: No way. Have you read [What scopes can shell variables have?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/what-scopes-can-shell-variables-have)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`source` it into current shell session.