# How to remove first segment or segments from PATH in shell script

Tags: shell-script, bashrc

I wanted to remove a CUDA directory from PATH by a sh script. The directories are showed by doing `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
```

I want only:

```
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
```

My script changes nothing but it DOES in terminal(this script will be automatically executed when I do `conda deactivate`):

```
export PATH=$(echo ${PATH} | sed -r 's|/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin||')
```

Could somebody tell me why and correct it into an elegant way?

Comment: If you change `PATH` within a script it won't change the value of `PATH` in the shell you are using to call the script.

Comment: To remove this first segment without `sed`: `PATH=${PATH#/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:}`.

Comment: @nohillside Is there a way to do this in a script?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42223/how-can-i-set-environment-variable-permanently-through-shell-script

Comment: @nohillside I write this .sh which runs when I shut down a virtual env of conda. So I want it `source` automatically

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=$(echo ${PATH} | sed -r 's|/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin||')
```

Or its more correct version:

```
export PATH="$(printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | sed 's|/usr/local/cuda-9\.0/bin||')"
```

Updates the content of the `$PATH` variable of the shell invoking that command by removing the first occurrence of `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin` in it. For instance, it would change a `/bin:/opt/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/v2:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin` to `/bin:/opt/v2:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin` which is not what you want.

To remove full elements, you could do:

```
export PATH="$(
  printf ':%s:\n' "$PATH" |
    sed '
      :1
      s|:/usr/local/cuda-9\.0/bin:|:|g; t1
      s|^:||; s|:$|'
)"
```

Or with zsh:

```
path=("${path[@]:#/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin}")
```

Note that if `$PATH` initially only contained `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin`, then the end result will be an empty `$PATH`. And empty `$PATH` means *search for executables in the current directory* which is not what you want. If that is a possibility, then you may want to make `$PATH` something like `/inexistent/to/disable/PATH/lookup`.

Note that in any case, it only changes the `$PATH` variable of the shell that runs that code. If you wanted that to affect the `$PATH` variable of the shell that invokes that script, you'd need that shell to *source* (as with the `.` or `source` command) that `deactivate` script, or make `deactivate` a *function* of that shell.

Or alternatively, you can have the `deactivate` script *output* the shell code that would be needed to remove those entries from `$PATH` (for instance by adding `export -p PATH` after having modified it) and make sure to invoke it as:

```
eval "$(deactivate)"
```

Within the shell where you want that entry to be removed from `$PATH`.

Something like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
path=("${path[@]:#/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin}")
export -p PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`. But your method already works:

```
$ PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
$ export PATH=$(echo ${PATH} | sed -r 's|/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin||')
$ echo $PATH
:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
```

Trying to set `PATH` within your current environment by *running* a script is not possible.

Comment: It works in terminal but not in script. Could you please edit it into the form for a script please?