# Am I using bash after this ordeal?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, osx, su

On Mountain Lion, host `Coguaro`, I login as user `coconutpowder` using `bash`:

```
Coguaro:~ coconutpowder$ echo $0
-bash
```

I need to run a command with elevated privileges so I try to `su` switch to `root` but it won't let me:

```
Coguaro:~ coconutpowder$ su -
Password:
su: Sorry
```

Feir enough. I read the `man` page for `su` and get this:

```
PAM is used to set the policy su(1) will use.
In particular, by default only users in the ``admin'' or ``wheel''
groups can switch to UID 0 (``root'').
```

I notice I am not part of either group allowed to `su` by doing this:

```
Coguaro:~ coconutpowder$ id
uid=502(coconutpowder) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts)
```

so I re-run the `su` command prefixing it with a `sudo`, which I am allowed to do as I am in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
/etc/sudoers: coconutpowder ALL=(ALL) ALL

Coguaro:~ coconutpowder$ sudo su -
Coguaro:~ root# echo $USER $0 $BASH_VERSION
root -sh 3.2.48(1)-release
Coguaro:~ root#
```

Now I have what I think is a problematic scenario as I am actually running `sh` for what I can see, that is my login shell for `root` after all, but I have the `BASH_VERSION` environment variable set from my earlier login, passed along via the `sudo` mechanism? Correct me if I am wrong.

This means some shell-detection tricks like this break:

```
if [ ${BASH_VERSION-not_running_within_bash} = not_running_within_bash ]; then
  # ...
fi
```

I am at a total loss as to how to properly `su` to `root` and have some way of determining with **certainty** whether I am using `bash` or not. The script uses Bash arrays extensively and could destroy filesystem paths if some values go spurious. I found the `ps -p $$` hacks mentioned elsewhere a bit of a hack (?!) so I am looking for the best way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish, considering I must login first as `coconutpowder` and can't just do so as `root` directly.

If I am doing the user switching wrong, I believe this question is distinctively different from the others that have proliferated around merely detecting the current (not *"default"* or *"assigned"*) shell.

So far I am edging towards parsing $0, possibly removing any prefixed `-` character to denote a login shell.

Unless any of you can teach me how to `su` to `root` with login (i.e. reading $HOME/.profile) and directly switch to `bash` from the default `sh`, which can't be changed.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do [sudo -i](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)? *The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified in the passwd(5) entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell...*

Comment: Just run `bash /your/script.sh` once you're root and make sure it has the right `#!` line.

Comment: Careful @Mat! The `#!` line bears **no** correlation here as you are effectively `source` calling your script if you prepend `bash` explicitly! Try by entering `#!/opt/local/bin/perl` there and see. That line is only checked when `chmod +x` executing the file!

Comment: That's why I tell you to run bash explicitly.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: same problem with `sudo -i`; try `echo ${!BASH*}` to see the exported `bash`-specifics still visible as `root`...

Comment: @Mat: I quote you "make sure it has the right #! line", that _"making sure"_ doesn't do anything; as explained. The line is ignore as a comment. Try it.

Comment: Anything prevents you from running `bash` just after logging in as root?

Comment: Nothing specifically, although this requires interactivity at the console? The question remains: if I `su` to `root` from my account, BASH_* variables are exported although I switch to `sh`. How to correctly detect the shell? `$0`? Other?

Comment: @Robottinosino: 1. for documentation if for nothing else, 2. you'll forget to explicitly run bash at some point or other, that'll usually save you since that line is supposed to be honored

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I have what I think is a problematic scenario as I am actually
>   running sh for what I can see, that is my login shell for root after
>   all, but I have the BASH_VERSION environment variable set from my
>   earlier login, passed along via the sudo mechanism? Correct me if I am
>   wrong.

Fortunately, you're wrong.  The `BASH_VERSION` and similar environment variables are **set**, but not **exported**, so they don't exist for child processes.

Compare the output of:

```
set | grep ^BASH
```

with

```
env | grep ^BASH
```

Both `set` and `env` display environment variables.  `set` is a shell built-in, and it sees the `BASH_*` variables.  `env` is an external program, and you'll notice that it doesn't see the `BASH_*` variables at all.

If you *did* want to export those variables to child processes, you could do it manually, and then it would show up in `env`:

```
$ export BASH_VERSION
$ env | grep ^BASH
BASH_VERSION=4.2.36(1)-release
```

But unless you've manually exported them like this, you can be fairly sure that the presence of `BASH_VERSION` means that you are actually running bash.  See also the output of `export -p` to figure out which variables are going to be exported in this way.

Comment: You taught me so much in your answer.. I was totally oblivious of the diff btw `set` and `env`! Thanks very much for your input, @Jim Paris!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're still using bash. `BASH_VERSION` is a shell variable, not an environment variable: it is only defined in that one shell, it is not exported to other processes. (See [Difference between environment variables and exported environment variables in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b) and [What scopes can shell variables have?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/what-scopes-can-shell-variables-have)).

Since `$0` shows `-sh`, that shell is a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). It's bash, but started under the name `sh`. When bash is started as `sh`, it behaves differently: it turns off some bash-specific features in order to be more compatible with other shells.

Don't bother with the `su` command. To get an interactive login shell as root, run `sudo -i`. You can specify an alternate shell to run, e.g. `sudo -i zsh`. To run an interactive shell that retains some of your environment variables and doesn't run root's `.profile` or other login files, run `sudo -s`.