# What is the difference in usage between shell variables and environment variables?

Tags: shell, command-line, environment-variables

I actually did not know there are two different types of variables I can access from the command line. All I knew is, that I can declare variables like:

```
foo="my dear friends"
bar[0]="one"
bar[1]="two"
bar[2]="three"
```

or accessing them with a $ sign, like:

```
echo $foo
echo ${bar[1]}
```

or using inbuilt variables, like:

```
echo $PWD
PATH=$PATH:"/usr/bin/myProg"
```

Now, I hear there are two (at least?) types of variables: shell variables and environment variables.

- What is the purpose of having two different types?
- How do I know which type a variable is?
- What are the typical usages for each one?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341372/differnce-between-the-shell-and-environment-variable-in-bash and http://www.tricksofthetrades.net/2015/06/14/notes-bash-env-variables/

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Environment variables are a list of `name=value` pairs that exist whatever the program is (shell, application, daemon…). They are typically inherited by children processes (created by a `fork`/`exec` sequence): children processes get their own copy of the parent variables.

Shell variables do exist only in the context of a shell. They are only inherited in subshells (i.e. when the shell is forked without an `exec` operation). Depending on the shell features, variables might not only be simple strings like environment ones but also arrays, compound, typed variables like integer or floating point, etc.

When a shell starts, all the environment variables it inherits from its parent become also shell variables (unless they are invalid as shell variables and other corner cases like `IFS` which is reset by some shells) but these inherited variables are tagged as exported<sup>1</sup>. That means they will stay available for children processes with the potentially updated value set by the shell. That is also the case with variables created under the shell and tagged as exported with the `export` keyword.

Array and other complex type variables cannot be exported unless their name and value can be converted to the `name=value` pattern, or when a shell specific mechanism is in place (e.g.: `bash` exports functions in the environment and some exotic, non POSIX shells like `rc` and `es` can export arrays).

So the main difference between environment variables and shell variables is their scope: environment variables are global while non exported shell variables are local to the script.

Note also that modern shells (at least `ksh` and `bash`) support a third shell variables scope. Variables created in functions with the `typeset` keyword are local to that function (The way the function is declared enables/disables this feature under `ksh`, and persistence behavior is different between `bash` and `ksh`). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28349/2594

<sup>1</sup><sub>This applies to modern shells like `ksh`, `dash`, `bash` and similar. The legacy Bourne shell and non Bourne syntax shells like `csh` have different behaviors.</sub>

Comment: Everything is inherited by children processes as children are created as a fork (an exact copy) of their parent. The point with environment variables is that they are passed to the `execve()` system call so are (typically) used to persist data over the _execution_ of other commands (in the same process).

Comment: Not all environment variables are translated to shell variables. Only those that are valid as a shell variable name (and with a few exceptions like `IFS` in some shells).

Comment: Shells like `rc`, `es` can export arrays using a adhoc encoding. `bash` and `rc` can also export functions using environment variables (again, using a special encoding).

Comment: In `ksh93`, `typeset` restricts the scope only in functions declared with the `function foo { ...; }` syntax, not with the Bourne (`foo() cmd`) syntax (and it's _static scoping_ not dynamic like in other shells).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for reviewing! Reply updated to take into account your remarks.

Comment: In the Bourne shell and csh (and that's different from POSIX shells), shell variables are created from environment variables, but are not _mapped_ / _tied_ unless you call `export` on them. That was broken in `ksh` and subsequently every POSIX shell. If you do `myvar=foo` in a `ksh` script and `myvar` happened to be in the environment when `ksh` was executed, then every command run afterwards in that script will get the modified value of the `myvar` variable. In `rc`, all variables are _exported_, there's no distinction between shell and environment variables.

Answer (score 19):

#### Shell variables

Shell variables are variables whose scope is in the current shell session, for example in an interactive shell session or a script.

You may create a shell variable by assigning a value to an unused name:

```
var="hello"
```

The use of shell variables is to keep track of data in the current session.  Shell variables usually have names with lower-case letters.

#### Environment variables

An environment variable is a shell variable which has been exported.  This means that it will be visible as a variable, not only in the shell session that created it, but also for any process (not just shells) that are started from that session.

```
VAR="hello"  # shell variable created
export VAR   # variable now part of the environment
```

or

```
export VAR="hello"
```

Once a shell variable has been exported, it stays exported until it is unset, or until its "export property" is removed (with `export -n` in `bash`), so there's usually no need to re-export it.  Unsetting a variable with `unset` deletes it (no matter if it's an environment variable or not).

Arrays and associative hashes in `bash` and other shells may not be exported to become environment variables. Environment variables must be simple variables whose values are strings, and they often have names consisting of upper-case letters.

The use of environment variables is to keep track of data in the current shell session, but also to allow any started process to take part of that data. The typical case of this is the `PATH` environment variable, which may be set in the shell and later used by any program that wants to start programs without specifying a full path to them.

The collection of environment variables in a process is often referred to as "the environment of the process". Each process has its own environment.

Environment variables can only be "forwarded", i.e. a child process can *never* change the environment variables in its parent process, and other than setting up the environment for a child process upon starting it, a parent process may not change the existing environment of a child process.

Environment variables may be listed with `env` (without any arguments). Other than that, they appear the same as non-exported shell variables in a shell session. *This is a bit special for the shell as most other programming languages don't usually intermix "ordinary" variables with environment variables* (see below).

`env` may also be used to set the values of one or several environment variables in the environment of a process without setting them in the current session:

```
env CC=clang CXX=clang++ make
```

This starts `make` with the environment variable `CC` set to the value `clang` and `CXX` set to `clang++`.

It may also be used to *clear* the environment for a process:

```
env -i bash
```

This starts `bash` but does not transfer the current environment to the new `bash` process (it will still *have* environment variables as it creates new ones from its shell initialization scripts).

#### Example of difference

```
$ var="hello"   # create shell variable "var"
$ bash          # start _new_ bash session
$ echo "$var"   # no output
$ exit          # back to original shell session
$ echo "$var"   # "hello" is outputted
$ unset var     # remove variable

$ export VAR="hello"  # create environment variable "VAR"
$ bash
$ echo "$VAR"         # "hello" is outputted since it's exported
$ exit                # back to original shell session
$ unset VAR           # remove variable

$ ( export VAR="hello"; echo "$VAR" )  # set env. var "VAR" to "hello" in subshell and echo it
$ echo "$VAR"         # no output since a subshell has its own environment
```

#### Other languages

There are library functions in most programming languages that allows for getting and setting the environment variables. Note that since environment variables are stored as a simple key-value relationship, they are not usually "variables" of the language. A program may fetch the value (which is always a character string) corresponding to a key (the name of the environment variable), but will then have to convert it to an integer or whatever data type the language expects the value to have.

In C, environment variables may be accessed using `getenv()`, `setenv()`, `putenv()` and `unsetenv()`. Variables created with these routines are inherited in the same way by any process that the C program starts.

Other languages may have special data structures for accomplishing the same thing, like the `%ENV` hash in Perl, or the `ENVIRON` associative array in most implementations of `awk`.

Comment: thx, brilliantly clear explanation. So the environment is like a big field wherein other programs can live and see each of the environment variables. Some programs have their private variables, only they themselves can see them, like the shell. but there is a mechanism to make private variables being seen by all called "export". If this is ok understood, than the only thing i am not sure about is if there can exist more than one environment at same time?

Comment: @sharkant Each running process has their own environment. This environment is inherited from the process that started it. There is never "cross-talk" between environments of different processes. The only way to change an environment variable in a process is for the process itself modifying it.

Comment: thx for claryfing my understanding. Each fish inside its own fish bowl. How about Processes which spawn other processes? Are processes and their child-processes all inside one environment or has each its own?

Comment: @sharkant The spawned process (the "child process") inherits the environment of the parent process, but they are separate.

Comment: AAAh, the kids get a copy of their parents environment and if they change their environment the parents environment does not change along.   One last thing: only the shell has the power to export variables? the shell is not the only process with private variables?

Comment: @sharkant There are library functions in most languages that allows for getting and setting the environment variables.  In C, this is done with `getenv()`, `setenv()`, `putenv()` and `unsetenv()`.  Variables created with these routines are inherited in the same way by any process that the C program starts.  Other languages may have special data structures for the same thing, like `%ENV` in Perl.

Comment: FWIW: the `exec*()` family of functions can also set the environment for the process being executed.

Answer (score 5):

Shell variables are difficult to duplicate.

```
$ FOO=bar
$ FOO=zot
$ echo $FOO
zot
$
```

Environment variables however can be duplicated; they are just a list, and a list can have duplicate entries. Here's `envdup.c` to do just that.

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char **environ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **newenv;
    int envcount = 0;

    if (argc < 2) errx(64, "Usage: envdup command [args ..]");

    newenv = environ;
    while (*newenv++ != NULL) envcount++;

    newenv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (envcount + 3));
    if (newenv == NULL) err(1, "malloc failed");
    memcpy(newenv, environ, sizeof(char *) * envcount);
    newenv[envcount]   = "FOO=bar";
    newenv[envcount+1] = "FOO=zot";
    newenv[envcount+2] = NULL;

    environ = newenv;
    argv++;
    execvp(*argv, argv);
    err(1, "exec failed '%s'", *argv);
}
```

Which we can compile and run telling `envdup` to then run `env` to show us what environment variables are set...

```
$ make envdup
cc     envdup.c   -o envdup
$ unset FOO
$ ./envdup env | grep FOO
FOO=bar
FOO=zot
$
```

This is perhaps only useful for finding bugs or other oddities in how well programs handle `**environ`.

```
$ unset FOO
$ ./envdup perl -e 'exec "env"' | grep FOO
FOO=bar
$ ./envdup python3 -c 'import os;os.execvp("env",["env"])' | grep FOO
FOO=bar
FOO=zot
$
```

Looks like Python 3.6 here blindly passes along the duplicates (a leaky abstraction) while Perl 5.24 does not. How about the shells?

```
$ ./envdup bash -c 'echo $FOO; exec env' | egrep 'bar|zot'
zot
FOO=zot
$ ./envdup zsh -c 'echo $FOO; exec env' | egrep 'bar|zot' 
bar
FOO=bar
$
```

Gosh, what happens if `sudo` only sanitizes the first environment entry but then `bash` runs with the second? Hello `PATH` or `LD_RUN_PATH` exploit. Is your `sudo` (and [everything else](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19749)?) [patched for that hole](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/d4dfb05db5d7)? Security exploits are neither "an anecdotal difference" nor just "a bug" in the calling program.

Comment: That's true but an anecdotal difference and arguably a bug of the program setting the duplicate variable.

Comment: See https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127158 (CVE-2016-2381)

Answer (score 1):

An **environment variable** is like a **shell variable**, but it’s not specific to the **shell**. 
All processes on **Unix systems** have **environment variable storage**.
*The main difference between environment and shell variables is :*
that the **operating** system passes all of your **shell’s environment variables** to programs that the shell runs, whereas shell variables cannot be accessed in the commands that you run.

`env –` The command allows you to run another program in a custom environment without modifying the current one. When used without an argument it will print a list of the current environment variables.
`printenv –` The command prints all or the specified environment variables.
`set –` The command sets or unsets shell variables. When used without an argument it will print a list of all variables including environment and shell variables, and shell functions.
`unset –` The command deletes shell and environment variables.
`export –` The command sets environment variables